# Desync pro controller from Switch quickly

Tags: controllers, nintendo-switch, super-smash-bros-ultimate

I'm looking for any way to make a switch pro controller lose it's pairing to a console, ideally in a way that is fast and consistent. I'm thinking that there may be a way to do this with a computer, but I need more information about how the syncing works in the first place for that.

To give more detail on what I'm trying to do, I'm looking for a fast and efficient solution to desync a switch pro controller from a console. We want to use these controllers in a competitive setting for smash Bros ultimate, but that requires desyncing the controller whenever you leave a console to prevent match interfere or delays. Right now, doing this through the switch itself takes about 30 seconds if practiced, the console has its joycons, and is not secured to the dock (so it can be lifted).

Ideally, with some understanding of how the controller is paired to the console via USB connection, this signal can be repeated on a second dummy device that serves as a desyncing station. The connection doesn't even need to be functional, it just needs to overwrite the existing saved connection so that the controller can't cause problems after leaving the station. Otherwise I'll start looking into ways to pair the controller wirelessly with a phone or laptop then immediately remove it, which may end up being easy/fast enough with a smaller work investment.

Comment: I know in smash ultimate you can respecify controllers in-game (in an in-game tourney, this is done automatically between rounds, outside that, I believe it's the Controllers option in the ZR menu). This fails to solve the issue of the home button being enabled still though.

Comment: Which is consistent with what we've found as well. There have also been issues with people having their controllers turn on in their bag while moving around and not being able to get around that at the character select screen (controller registers as active because the stick is moving around).

Comment: I know you *can* connect a pro controller to a PC via bluetooth, but I'm not sure how you would identify an individual controller when pairing in a "there are a lot of controllers in the area" context, so that would probably be slower than using a second switch.

Comment: The second switch is what we ended up using, just have one console permanently unused for tournament matches. However, that also means that a tournament needs to have a $300 USB port on hand just to sync against. If we can replicate the same functionality on an Android phone though via an app, then suddenly numerous people could have a desync station in their pocket.

Comment: I think this is a good question, but it may help if you open with your true intent (quickly de-synching in a competitive setting) and if your title reflected that. As it stands, your whole first paragraph can probably be taken out and your title re-written.

Comment: That's a fair critique. My fear was that if I phrased the question wrong, I would get a bunch of answers about how there isn't a way to make a pro controller forget it's pairing. Right now there isn't, and there have been a number of threads in various places stating as much. My hope is to find some details about how the Bluetooth pairing works in general so that I can maybe recreate it in code.

Comment: Saying it that way, I might have better luck on the normal stack exchange page. The more I think about it, the more my question is about what I hope to be a generic Bluetooth capabilities. There is a chance that the syncing via USB method is proprietary to Sony and Nintendo for their implementations, but that doesn't sound likely.

Comment: The end goal is to use this solution for s Super Smash Bros tournament, but couldn't the same question be asked for any game played in a similar competitive setting on the Switch? I don't think the SSBU tag adds to this question.